Looking for assistance debugging a SQL deadlock
I am looking for some guidance on how to best debug this deadlock. I'm using EF Core and believe the line causing the issue is this: _context.InventoryTracks.Remove(id). This is the only place in code a remove is performed on that table. That would generate the DELETE statement shown below. There is a keylock, which may come from a prior query with an Include (or something else), but I'm not understanding why there are 2 processes here doing the same exact thing (the delete) and one becomes the victim. Prior to the .Remove, there is a .RemoveRange and .SaveChanges on a related table. Interestingly enough, if that isn't done at all, deleting the InventoryTracks record would automatically clean up what is being removed in the .RemoveRange call as cascade delete is set on the DB. Any suggestions on how to better debug this are much appreciated. Thanks.
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process15c4352d468" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process15c4352d468" taskpriority="0" logused="604" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057654391668736 (b4d7f128fa4c)" waittime="1111" ownerId="2312262978" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2024-09-25T10:07:12.913" XDES="0x154f76b8428" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="4" kpid="4460" status="suspended" spid="96" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2024-09-25T10:07:12.933" lastbatchcompleted="2024-09-25T10:07:12.923" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.923" clientapp="MyAPI" hostname="ProdServer" hostpid="14488" loginname="AD\user" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2312262978" currentdb="5" currentdbname="MyDB" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="86" stmtend="258" sqlhandle="0x0200000060b625062105144680a22bc60c73056ff9771a4c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@p2 int,@p3 varbinary(8))SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [dbo].[InventoryTrack]
WHERE [InventoryTrackId] = @p2 AND [RowVersion] = @p3;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process15aef12e108" taskpriority="0" logused="960" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057654391668736 (cf6d78acbc8a)" waittime="1121" ownerId="2312262977" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2024-09-25T10:07:12.903" XDES="0x1552a7c0428" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="7" kpid="9872" status="suspended" spid="125" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2024-09-25T10:07:12.923" lastbatchcompleted="2024-09-25T10:07:12.913" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.913" clientapp="MyAPI" hostname="ProdServer" hostpid="14488" loginname="AD\user" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2312262977" currentdb="5" currentdbname="MyDB" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="86" stmtend="258" sqlhandle="0x0200000060b625062105144680a22bc60c73056ff9771a4c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@p2 int,@p3 varbinary(8))SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [dbo].[InventoryTrack]
WHERE [InventoryTrackId] = @p2 AND [RowVersion] = @p3;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057654391668736" dbid="5" objectname="MyDB.dbo.PickListItem" indexname="PK_PickListItem" id="lock150c6d0f000" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057654391668736">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process15aef12e108" mode="RangeS-U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process15c4352d468" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057654391668736" dbid="5" objectname="MyDB.dbo.PickListItem" indexname="PK_PickListItem" id="lock15db6cb0200" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057654391668736">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process15c4352d468" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process15aef12e108" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>

Here is the EF code from the project which was created a while ago by people who are no longer around and there is no accompanying documentation. I removed code before and after the area of consideration.
//code above, omitted for brevity

incompleteTotesForPick = _context.PickListTotes
    .Where(plt => plt.PickStatusId != (int)PickStatus.Completed)
    .Include(pli => pli.PickListItem.InventoryTrack)
    .Any(
        ip =>
            ip.PickListItem.InventoryTrack.InventoryTrackId ==
            pickListTote.PickListItem.InventoryTrackId);

var inventoryTrack = pickListTote.PickListItem.InventoryTrack;

var pickListItemTotes = _context.PickListTotes
    .Where(pl => pl.PickListItem.PickListItemId == pickListTote.PickListItemId);

totalPickQty = pickListItemTotes.Sum(q => q.PickedQty);

_context.PickListTotes.RemoveRange(pickListItemTotes);  
_context.SaveChanges();

if (!incompleteTotesForPick)
{
    _context.InventoryTracks.Remove(InventoryTrack);    //this must generate the delete and be where the deadlock occurs 
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

//more code, omitted for brevity


What's the actual code?  _context.InventoryTracks.Remove(id) doesn't delete anything, it marks the entity as Deleted. When SaveChanges is called all pending changes will be persisted in a single database transaction. SaveChanges on a related table there's no such thing. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-Of-Work and DbContext.SaveChanges persists all changes to all entities. Does the real code use explicit transactions to fix the problems caused by calling SaveChanges multiple times?

What's the relation between MyDB.dbo.PickListItem and dbo.InventoryTrack ? If there's a CASCADE DELETE foreign key constraint, are the FK columns indexed? If not, the server would have to scan the entire foreign table to find matches, locking any rows it scans in the process

@PanagiotisKanavos I've included some c# code around the area of consideration. The real code does not use explicit transactions.

The code does use SaveChanges multiple times though, which is a bug. Especially inside a loop. Instead of deleting N rows at once, at best you end up with N DELETE operations.  Does the code use TransactionScope?

It's unexpected in the first place that there are two sessions trying to delete records in the same table at the same time. It looks like for some odd reason the code runs twice. Just for diagnosing: what if you remove the first deletion (pickListItemTotes), since that is done by cascaded delete anyway?
